# Dash dropdown that allows multiple selection but is not clearable

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Is there a way to create a Dropdown menu that allows multi-selection, but does not allow the user to clear the selected options (i.e. have nothing selected)?

As far as I can see, the multi flag overrides the clearable flag, i.e. the following code allows multi-selection and is clearable.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

dcc.Dropdown(
    id='column-plot-list',
    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['opt1', 'opt2']],
    value='opt1',
    multi=True,
    clearable=False
)
```

Comment: there is no option for doing so because nothing selected is an option for multiselection. the best way to avoid this is to set a default value and display a waring in the callback when the user is trying to change the selection to an empty one

Comment: Yeah ok fair enough - thanks for the suggestion as well.